# How does one implement a custom sync provider?

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-sync-framework

Yes I have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd937818) but its very unclear, especially when you want to write a provider for Outlook so, maybe you know of a normal tutorial on how to do this, or similar?

I'm guessing, after staring for 4-5hours at MSDN code I could achieve enlightenment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found an old article on MSDN about the whole topic. It's not that helpful and does not provide full samples. But the author actually [wrote a book](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430210054) about that topic. They even provide lengthy examples which are [available as public download](https://github.com/apress/pro-sync-framework). You can find the implementation of a custom sync provider inside the archive at "\Pro Sync Framework\Chapter III\Code\CustomProvider\CustomProvider.sln".